# css vertical-align not working

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Please help to vertically align the tittle.
It seems not working properly.

[image]

```
<html>
<body>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
html *
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;}
.Title
    {
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
    border: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    }

.btn{
    color:white;
    background-color:#8CC152;
    margin: 0px !important;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.btn:hover{
    background-color:#A0D468;
}

.btn-next{
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    float:right;
}

.btn-prev{
    border-radius: 4px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>

<div class='Title'>
    <p>
        This is a title
        <a href='?m=1'><span class='btn btn-prev'>LEFT</span></a>
        <a href='?m=2'><span class='btn btn-next'>RIGHT</span></a>
        </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a `line-height` for the paragraph

```
p {
 line-height: 32px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
p {
  line-height: 32px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    html * {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    .Title {
      width: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: larger;
      border: solid;
      border-width: thin;
    }
    .btn {
      color: white;
      background-color: #8CC152;
      margin: 0px !important;
      width: auto;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.42857;
      text-align: center;
      white-space: nowrap;
      vertical-align: middle;
      cursor: pointer;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      background-image: none;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    .btn:hover {
      background-color: #A0D468;
    }
    .btn-next {
      border-radius: 4px;
      border-top-left-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
      float: right;
    }
    .btn-prev {
      border-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<div class='Title'>
  <p>
    This is a title
    <a href='?m=1'><span class='btn btn-prev'>LEFT</span></a>
    <a href='?m=2'><span class='btn btn-next'>RIGHT</span></a>
  </p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```